# How to create a new notification configuration on a specified bucket using terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I am having problems creating a new notification config for a gcp bucket using the example shown on the [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_notification).

I am using the same code but get an error when i run the command.

```
resource "google_storage_notification" "notification" {
  bucket         = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  payload_format = "JSON_API_V1"
  topic          = google_pubsub_topic.topic.id
  event_types    = ["OBJECT_FINALIZE", "OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE"]
  custom_attributes = {
    new-attribute = "new-attribute-value"
  }
  depends_on = [google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding.binding]
}

// Enable notifications by giving the correct IAM permission to the unique service account.

data "google_storage_project_service_account" "gcs_account" {
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding" "binding" {
  topic   = google_pubsub_topic.topic.id
  role    = "roles/pubsub.publisher"
  members = ["serviceAccount:${data.google_storage_project_service_account.gcs_account.email_address}"]
}

// End enabling notifications

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name     = "test_bucket"
  location = "US"
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name = "test_topic"
}
```

Ouput on the console

```
Error: Error retrieving IAM policy for pubsub topic "projects/myproject/topics/test_topic": googleapi: Error 403: User not authorized to perform this action.
│
│   with google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding.binding,
│   on main.tf line 109, in resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding" "binding":
│  109: resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_binding" "binding" {
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here as i am using the exact code. Only changed the bucket name and the topic name from the original sample.

Comment: Please add any errors as text to the question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the credentials used by Terraform to apply your configuration do not have sufficient privileges to create the IAM binding. Have a look at [the specific permissions needed to perform different operations](https://cloud.google.com/why-google-cloud) and check that you have all required permissions.

Note that:

To **create a topic** you need the `pubsub.topics.create` permission, which is included in the `editor` and `pubsub.editor` roles.

To **get/set the IAM policy** for a topic, you need the `pubsub.topics.getIamPolicy` and `pubsub.topics.setIamPolicy` respectively, which is included in the `owner` and `pubsub.admin` roles, but **NOT** in the `editor` or `pubsub.editor` roles.